# How would I populate the UserL List?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am looking to populate the `UserL` list, but I have had some major problems with that so far. My small brain could not find any solutions on Google.

```
public partial class RootObject
{
    public List<User> UserL = new List<User>();
}

public partial class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public double UserID { get; set; }
    public long WarnCount { get; set; }
    public long Level { get; set; }
    public long XP { get; set; }
}

public partial class RootObject
{
    public static List<User> FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(File.ReadAllText(json), Converter.Settings);
}

public static class Serialize
{
    public static string ToJson(this RootObject self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
}
```

Here is the JSON I am trying to deserialize:

```
{
    "UserArr": [
        {
            "Username": "User2",
            "UserID": 307618173073489920,
            "WarnCount": 0,
            "Level": 0,
            "XP": 0
        },
        {
            "UserName": "User1",
            "UserID": 385453321999089664,
            "WarnCount": 0,
            "Level": 0,
            "XP": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What issues are you facing? Any errors? First things i see are 1. why are you passing `json` then attempting to open a file to then deseralise in `FromJson`? 2. You're not actually setting `UserL =` anywhere in this code other than initialising the list, is there more code you've left out?

Comment: 1. Not sure how I reply to that. That is mostly how I have done my Deserializations up until now. Is there something else I am required to do?
2. That is the problem. I would want to populate that UserL, but I am not sure how. I require the user list to be populated in order to be able to call its members when needed. And no, that is the only code required to work it, other being me attempting to populate the list in unsuccessful ways.

Comment: Only error the console had been outputting so far was: `Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Cuvue.JSONManagment.User]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
Path 'UserArr', line 2, position 11.`

Comment: 1. My bad, the parameter name being "json" makes it sound like you are passing a json string to the method, instead you're passing a json file name.. makes sense now. 2. That's an issue with the json you're using - can you post it?

Comment: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/23dd1bba9a6e4b98b432ad14256a6cc3 a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have things set up now is.. You need to create an instance of `RootObject` and then use the method `FromJson` to set the value. Either this needs to be after initialisation or in the constructor for `RootObject`.

```
RootObject root = new RootObject
{
    UserL = RootObject.FromJson("json1.json")
};
```

The error you're getting is due to the format of the json you're trying to deseralise. Because you're deserialising directly into a list, not a class that contains a list, the outermost part needs to be an `[]` array.

Taking the json you posted as an example you need to remove the UserArr part and change

```
{  
   "UserArr":[  
      {  
         "Username":"User2",
         "UserID":307618173073489920,
         "WarnCount":0,
         "Level":0,
         "XP":0
      },
      {  
         "UserName":"User1",
         "UserID":385453321999089664,
         "WarnCount":0,
         "Level":0,
         "XP":0
      }
   ]
}
```

into

```
[  
   {  
      "Username":"User2",
      "UserID":307618173073489920,
      "WarnCount":0,
      "Level":0,
      "XP":0
   },
   {  
      "UserName":"User1",
      "UserID":385453321999089664,
      "WarnCount":0,
      "Level":0,
      "XP":0
   }
]
```

If the json is not modifiable then you could change how you deserialise. Rather than deserialising directly to the list, deserialise to the `RootObject` class. This will require you to rename the property `UserL` to be `UserArr` to match the json e.g.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<User> UserArr = new List<User>();
}

RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText("json.json"));
```

and keeping with your `FromJson` method

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<User> UserArr = new List<User>();
    public static RootObject FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(json));
}

RootObject root = RootObject.FromJson("json.json");
```